# Python API pull to SQL Server (Updating rows)

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, sql-update

I have a question about updating information in a database from an API.

I am pulling tickets from a specific software through python through the API.  I am putting those rows of data into our database (SQL Server) and that works just great.  ***HOWEVER***, what doesn't work is updating those tickets.  I can't pull all of the tickets again because there is too much data to grab at a time, therefore I need a way to stay up to date with the ticket statuses without pulling in all of the tickets at once.

Any ideas? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You should provide more details: what data you have in your database and what exactly your application is expected to do with the data

Comment: This is really too broad a question, and may well get closed as such. The only way to pull changed records only, is to store in your backend when you last pulled the data, and have it track if anything changes, and then you call an API call saying "Give me any records which have changed". Or you can poll the API slowly in the background, asking for a few records at a time and comparing them to what you have in your database. There are many ways to solve this, its depends a lot on your architecture, and only you can determine "best".

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean below

```
   Update destination d
    Set d.data= (Select data from source s where
    s.id =d.id and s.others!=d.others)
```